# How to update ID in table 2 from table 1 in Oracle sql

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I have two tables, the first has columns `ID, email, password`. Second table has `id, salary, company, dept`.

Tables 1 col Id is auto-generated number.

I have a Java form that collects all these values except id  and saves to db using procedure.

Now whenever I add details to the Java form, how can I pass it to table 2 along the other values from java form?

I tried `insert into table2(id) select id from table1;`
and `insert into table2(salary, company) values (x, y);`

How do I combine these two statement using a procedure in SQL?

Comment: Can you please format your question better and make your question more obvious? Also what are the steps you tried, and what are your code examples?

Comment: Yess done, is it clear now

Comment: I editted it because it was not clear at all. Use the proper formatting for codes examples, and make your questions more obvious.

Comment: **Suspicious double posting - this looks like cheating on an exam or such** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115980/how-to-update-id-from-one-table-to-another

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1) Find out function or procedure that generates id which will be in your code, 
 then get that id and insert in table 2
OR

2) You have to get row id of the row which was inserted last, row id is unique for every table:

```
SELECT MAX (ROWID) FROM table1
```

Get last id using rowid:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX (ROWID) FROM table1)
```

Now use its id and insert into table 2, this has to be done before another new row is inserted into table 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
create or replace procedure proc (em in varchar2,pass in varchar2,sal in number,cmp in varchar2,d in number)
as
sid number;
begin
insert into table1(id,email,password) values(<autogenerated_number>,em,pass) returning id into sid;
insert into table2(id,salary,company,dept) values(sid,sal,cmp,d);
commit;
end;
```