# how to update id from one table to another

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have two tables:

- `TABLE1` has columns(id,name,password),
- `TABLE2` has columns(id,salary,dept).

`id` in `table1` is auto-generated sequence number.  Data is added using java form.  I wanted to show `table1` id in `table2` along with other details.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRO5(y in varchar,z in varchar,x in varchar,
                                c in varchar,d in varchar,b in number, j in number)
as BEGIN
    insert into emp_general(username,email,password) values(y,z,x);
    insert into SALARY_DET(username ,salary,company,dept) values(y,c,d,b);

    set j := INSERT INTO salary_det(ID) SELECT ID FROM emp_general;
END;
```

Comment: Which database?

Comment: ORACLE SQL DATABASE

Comment: SET LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: Change your insert statement like this insert into emp_general(username,email,password) values(y,z,x) returning ID into SID;

Comment: where should I place the "SET LID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); " in procedure.it dint work...

Comment: **Suspicious double posting - this looks like cheating on an exam or such**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115577/how-to-update-id-in-table-2-from-table-1-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
 select @Id = convert(int,scope_identity());
```

For Oracle

```
 SET LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```